# Why is a pointer needed for initialising an object on the heap, but not on the stack?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, heap-memory, stack-memory

For example in these two codes, one requires no pointer, the other does. Why is this? If myObject1 isn't a pointer, then what is it exactly?

```
class Object{
…
};


int main(){
    // Create instance on the stack
    Object myObject1;

    // Create instance on the heap
    Object *myObject2 = new Object;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The pointer isn't *required*, just a convenient way of remembering where the object is. Using just `new Object;` also creates an object on the heap, but then we don't know where it is.

Answer (score 7):

Both of your declarations are definitions of objects that will have automatic storage duration. That is, they will both be destroyed at the end of the function. The first one is declaring an `Object` type object and the second is an `Object*` type object.

It just happens that the initializer for `myObject2` is a *new-expression*. A new expression dynamically allocates an object and returns a pointer to it. `myObject2` is being initialized with the pointer to the dynamically allocated `Object`.

So you are witnessing two different ways of creating objects. One is with a variable definition and one is with a *new-expression*.

It doesn't really make sense any other way. Imagine that a *new-expression* didn't return a pointer to the object but referred to the object directly. You might then write something like so:

```
Object myObject2 = new Object();
```

However, C++ works with value semantics by default. This means that the dynamically allocated object would be copied into `myObject2` and then you've lost track of it. You don't have any way to get the address of that object any more. A *new-expression* returns a pointer so that you have a handle to the dynamically allocated object.

You might say, "well that's how I'd write it in Java!" But that's because Java works in a different way. In Java, `myObject2` is a reference that you are setting to point to the new `Object` object. It doesn't copy the object in any way.

C++ doesn't require that you have to use a pointer when you dynamically allocate an object. In fact, you could do something like this (which is kind of the Java equivalent):

```
Object& myObject2 = *(new Object());
```

But that's a very bad idea. It suddenly masks the fact that the object was dynamically allocated and it would be very easy to make a mistake and forget to destroy the object (which you don't have to care about in Java). At least a pointer might remind you to do so. However, even that can lead to buggy or unclear code, which is why it is recommended that you use a smart pointer when possible.

So in short: that's just how a *new-expression* behaves. It dynamically allocates an object and then returns a pointer to it.

Answer (score 4):

It's an *instance* (or an object) of a class. `myObject2` *points* to an instance of a class.

You can have pointers pointing to variables on the stack as well:

```
int main()
{
    Object myObject1;
    Object* pointerToObjectOnStack = &myObject1;
}
```

A pointer may point to anywhere; the stack, the heap or to a global variable (which is neither on the stack or on the heap).

Answer (score 1):

> For example in these two codes, one requires no pointer, the other
>   does. Why is this?

Becuase you wrote them in that way in an (unguaranteed) attempt to match the comments you wrote above of them.

> If myObject1 isn't a pointer, then what is it exactly?

An `Object`. That is, an object of type `Object`. That is, an instance of the `Object` class.

Comment: `myObject2` is also an object, which is a pointer to an object of type `Object`.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Yes. I never denied that. myObject2 is an object of type Object *, and myObject1 is an object of type Object.

Answer (score 1):

The `myObject1` is an `Object` allocated in stack.

[Here](http://www.tenouk.com/ModuleW.html) you will find a more exact information about the memory.

In two words:

1. All local variables (including object instances) on the functions are allocated in **stack**.
2. All dynamically allocated (using `new` or `malloc()`) data is allocated in **heap**.

Answer (score 1):

When you allocate an object on a stack, compiler does all the dirty work for you (allocation/dealocation), so effectively you don't need a pointer to use the object. When you refer to myObject1, you are refering to the `Object` itself, you can simply access its fields, methods and so on.

Note, that you can always obtain a pointer to a variable on the stack by using the `&` operator.

```
Object myObject1; // This is the live instance of Object
Object * pObject1 = &myObject1; // Here you can obtain a pointer
                                // to myObject1
myObject1.someField = 42;       // Accessing myObject1's data
```

On the other hand, allocating objects on the heap requires you to manage these objects (allocate/deallocate them manually using new/delete, malloc/free etc.), so first you get the pointer to memory, where the object is located and to use it, you have to dereference it using the `*` operator.

```
Object * myObject1 = new Object(); // Here you construct the Object manually
                                   // and get the pointer to place, where Object
                                   // was allocated.
(*myObject1).someField = 42;       // Accessing myObject1's data, notice the 
                                   // dereference (*)
myObject1->someField = 42;         // The same, written more easily
```

Answer (score 0):

Every object which is part of a function is allocated on the stack when the function is called along with some metadata. This metadata structure is defined when the compiler compile the function -> this lead to a fast access to those variable from the function (there relative position doesn't change). also this memory is always (automatically) free when the function returns.

While the heap is setting in a different part of the memory and can or can't be used according to logic.

One thing you have a mistake with, and it will be easy to show by splitting you code to two lines:

```
class Object{
…
};

int main(){
    // Create instance of Object on the stack
    Object myObject1;

    // Create instance of a pointer to Object on the stack
    Object *myObject2;

    // Create instance of Object on the Heap and assigned its address to the pointer.
    myObject2 = new Object;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If variable is allocated on stack, compiler implicitly generates a pointer for you.

i.e. `Object myObject1; myObject1.foo();`
will be compiled as

```
Object* myObject1_implicit_ptr = new(alloca(sizeof(Object))) Object;
myObject1_implicit_ptr->foo();
```

(`alloca` allocates memory on stack)

---

In `Object myObject1;`, `myObject1` is a name of memory location where the instance of object resides, i.e. an alias of its address (relative to stack frame pointer).
We can query that address with `operator&` and store into a pointer (a variable which holds an address):

```
Object myObject1; // myObject1 == stack-frame-pointer + 123
Object* myObject1_ptr = &myObject1;
```

Comment: This is more confusing than it is clarifying, if you ask me. Although technically it is equivalent, I have a hard time justifying that the compiler "actually" does this more than anything else.

Comment: While this *might* reflect how it is compiled to machine code, using placement `new` on memory from `alloca` will certainly *not* help to understand the actual concepts of the OP's question in any way and will probably do more bad than good.

Comment: @MagnusHoff Well, in the assembly it will probably indeed work similar. Allocate memory for the object on the stack and invoke each member function with a pointer to that memory. But I totally agree that this doesn't really help anyone.

Comment: the question is "why pointer is not needed for stack-allocated objects". I wrote that it is needed, but compiler hides it. what's so confusing about it?

Comment: (Not my downvote). This is not how modern compilers allocate stack space. They do so upfront, for all variables combined, taking their lifetimes into account. I.e. `char* _StackFrame = alloca(_Size); Object* _Ptr_myObject = _StackFrame + _Offset_myObject; new(_Ptr_myObject) Object;`

Comment: @MSalters, yep, *after optimization* multiple `alloca` can be merged into single one, or eliminated by reusing space allocated for other variables.

Comment: @Abyx: Just checked un-optimized code from MSVC2005, and even that old compiler emits a single `sub esp,16Ch` for all allocations combined. It would be a mighty mess to do otherwise. You'd need space on the stack to hold the pointers to the alloca'd memory on the stack.

Comment: @MSalters, nope, you don't need to have such pointers because they point to addresses known at compile-time. (stack frame based addresses)